Error on loading screen when trying to Cmd+R
Model is MacBook Pro mid 2009
The error:
panic (cpu 0 caller 0xfffff8012d9) Process 1 exec of /sbin/launchbin failed, errrno 5 @library/caches....

There are many lines but is hard to read, because in a second the Mac turns off and macOS tries to boot up. I had to turn on it many times to read that part.
Then I noticed that one of the two golden pins above where the battery conector is in the cpu board is not broken but a little gold that surrounds it got broken so now the pin can be moved to the side, normally it can be pressed down as a button but now because a part of what sorounded it is broken it can move to that side (dint know how else explain it)
So when I touched it and turned it on I got a different error number -- the 0xffff changed to 8013
How do I fix this, Does that have to do with this error?

If I am understanding you correctly one of the pins that attaches to the charger is loose on the system board. It is quite possible that this is (at least one of) the issue(s) you are experiencing. That Mac is way out of warranty. If you can find a reputable shop that does board-level fixes on Macs that is where you could take it. I am not sure if even Apple would fix this out of warranty for a (premium) price.
